# Call a method on v-if inside vue.js file

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am pretty new to vue.js . I have a minor issue to fix and need one help.

So I have one vue.js file which has an existing method let's say,

```
doSomething(){
   //updates few properties here
}
```

Now I have a list/array **computed** property let's say **pageUser()** , and I want to invoke doSomething whenever `pageUser.length == 0`.

How we can achieve this in **vue.js** , can we use v-if in any tag and from there can invoke the method, or what are the other ways to do this.

Comment: It seems like you can try to add a watch for `pageUser` array but that might not be the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger your method in computed property:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      user: [{id: 1}, {id: 2}],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    pageUser() {
      if (this.user.length) return this.user 
      this.doSomething()
      return 'no user'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething() {
      console.log('done something')
    },
    empty() {
      this.user = []
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="empty">empty</button>
  <div>{{ pageUser }}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Nikola , sorry i was not clear in my question , pageUser is not something returned form data() , pageUser() is part of compute: {}

Comment: @Sourabh hey mate, check again pls I updated my answer. Just return right values or trigger your function in computed property

Answer (score 2):

Computed properties should be side effect free. What you're looking for is a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html). You can watch your computed list and when its empty call the method.

```
watch(pageUsers, () => {
    if(pageUsers.length === 0) {
        doSomething();
    }
})
```